# ng-hide does not hide the selected item

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<ion-nav-buttons ng-hide="items.length == 0" side="left"> 
   <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="enableEdit()">{{EditText}}</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

The problem is that I still see the item even though items is `[]` and the length is 0.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried the opposit approach - `ng-show="items.length"` ??

Comment: try like this ng-hide="!items.length"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `<ion-nav-buttons>` is just a way to place the proper dom elements in the right place. It doesn't act like an element itself. The easiest way to solve this is to place the ng-hide attribute on the button itself (or on a div that surrounds all the buttons).

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left"> 
   <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-hide="items.length === 0" ng-click="enableEdit()">{{EditText}}</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```